# CSS color property not working correctly on @media print

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm building a web app which basically consists of a large form which can then be printed after submission.

However, the text on my print document seems to never be affected by both `color` and `font-weight` CSS properties.

Here is a small section of the document as it looks like on screen:

[image]

However, when printing, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

The font is the same but for some reason no styles are applied to it. I have NO overriding CSS settings for `@media print`, so shouldn't it just look exactly the same?

Why aren't my normal styles being applied to the print document (by print document I mean the document that appears when you click your browser's Print button)?

**EDIT:** Posting some example code to illustrate my problem, as requested:

```
@media print {

    html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        color: yellow !important;
    }
}
```

In the above snippet, every attribute will work correctly *except* color, even when using the `!important` tag. I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: My stylesheet is about 2000 lines, separated in several documents, is there something specific you want to see?

Comment: I've added an example to illustrate my problem, even though the images that I used in the original post were taken without any @media print queries applied to them. What I don't understand is why the font seems to default to its standard weight and black color.

Comment: Could try to combine CSS and HTML to a point were this can be easily tested? Aka, a mock HTML page with the fewest lines of CSS to replicate the problem. The issue is that your problem could be _anywhere_. It could be CSS that overwrites it, it could be inline-styles, browser behaviour, potentially a lack of the `html` element in print? Try to eliminate as much of the cruft and post us a condensed problem case.

Comment: Since !important doesn't work I'd rule out CSS overwriting problems, I haven't used !important anywhere else on my stylesheet, but I do use bootstrap. The same for inline-styles: I have none. I'm guessing it might be some bower or npm package I installed.

Comment: built a most simple implementation. Does this happen if you have `body { color: red; } @media print { body { color: green; } }`?

Comment: As I said in the example I've added, nothing happens when I add color even with @media print: the font always appears black.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the source of the problem: Bootstrap.

I used Chrome's inspector tools to poke around print styles in the Emulation tab, as you can see on the following picture:

[image]

I then selected the element whose color was not being applied correctly, which led me to this little gem:

```
@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    // Other code...
}
```

Bootstrap was overriding all my styles with a nasty `*` `!important` combo, *which will even override* an `html {color: yellow !important}` because of [CSS's specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

To solve my problem I can either delete the above snippet from Bootstrap or make all my own colors `!important`.

Comment: Yes, I have had the same problem before.  Once you mentioned Bootstrap in your question, I knew what the issue was.  Glad you found it though!

Comment: I know this isn't a constructive comment, but I've been searching for **hours** for the answer, and found this - life saver! I could not for the life of me remember the emulator - could've saved hours of my time. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The "Eumlation" Tab does not exist anymore. Currently it is called "Rendering", then find the checkbox "Emulate CSS Media".

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading to Bootstrap 3.3.7, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing any issues appearing when I use your code (slightly modified for ease of obviousness):

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: red !important;
}
@media print {
  html {
    color: yellow !important;
  }
}
```

```html
Red for web, Yellow for print
```

My print preview in safari displays the text as yellow (ish 0 it looks a little bit greenish but the color most certainly ids *not* red). I am not sure where you issue will lie, but it's not with this code.

Comment: Thank you for testing! I am using Chromium on Ubuntu, would it be possible for it to be a system issue?

Comment: I have tested with the latest Chrome on Mac and it does the same - it works. It might be that you are running that specific browser. Do some testing on other devices, as the particular OS and browser you are running it not really popular enough to warrant finding out why this is happening.

Comment: I just tested on a mac and still my font is always black. It must be something with my code, but I have absolutely no idea what could possibly override an !important flag on the very last line of my stylesheet...

Comment: Just wondering... The link to your style sheet does not contain media queries, right? Like `<link rel="stylesheet" media="web" />` or something?

Comment: No, and it is the last link (all styles that belong to packages come before it).

Comment: Hmmmm... Thats is particularly odd. One thing that happens to me every once in a while is an _incorrect_ space. It looks like one but it isn't - I often type it when I try to type a space and a hash in order. On my mac, `alt + space` gives a different space which isn't allowed in CSS. Just throwing it out there to check...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using bootstrap but encountered the same issue and could not resolve it for days.  Finally found that changing the "font-family" on print style helped.

```
@media print {
body
{
    font-family: system-ui, sans-serif, auto !important;
}
```