# All browsers doesn't print red font red but black

Tags: css, printing

I have a small template that I'd like to print. In regular html view it works properly but when I want to print it the font is always black - independently from @media print and the same problem occurs in chrome, edge, firefox..

what it looks like normally:

[image]

what it looks like when I want to print it

[image]

HTML Template:

app.component.html

```
<div class="tischkarten-container">
  <app-tischkarte *ngFor="let x of times" [tischnummer]="x"></app-tischkarte>
</div>
```

tischkarte.component.html

```
<div class="tischkarte">
  <div class="tischkarte_nummer">{{tischnummer < 10 ? '&nbsp;&nbsp;'+tischnummer : tischnummer}}</div>
  <img src="../../assets/tischkarte-motiv-cropped.png" class="tischkarte_motiv"/>
</div>
```

CSS:
styles.css

```
   @media print {
      div {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-after  : always;
        page-break-before : always;
      }
    }
```

app.component.css

```
    .tischkarten-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

tischkarte.component.css

```
.tischkarte {
  background-size: contain;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 12cm;
  width: 9cm;
  flex-basis: 9cm;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.tischkarte_motiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 60%;
  right: 0;
}

.tischkarte_nummer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 210px;
  font-family: "Closure";
  color: #9e0200;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  margin-left: -18px;
}

@media print {
  .tischkarte_nummer {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
    color: #9e0200;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your printer driver is set to only use monochrome for the printing of text. Dithering often looks awful, so the printer would rather avoid that. To test that, you can try if a "pure" colour works, such as cyan (#0FF) or magenta (#F0F).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS color property not working correctly on @media print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950554/css-color-property-not-working-correctly-on-media-print)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or a CSS reset, normalize or similar? If yes, most of these have a `color: black` declaration for print with an `!important` flag.

Comment: Thank you alot, it was bootstrap and its "!important"-flag!